# World state in Ethereum - Always 1 turn lagging?

Tags: transactions, evm, state-trie, state-transition, state

About the data in Ethereum block header, there is the State root from the World state trie.
However this World state trie contain the whole Accounts states (EOA + CA).
In a block, we have transactions which affects the Accounts states.

So with this informations, one question persist :
The State root we find in each block header, is from the World state before transactions, or after ?
So a new World State is it updated in real time, and the State root in block header is the result of the whole transactions ? Or the State root have always 1 turn lagging?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The state root saved in a block is the result after processing all the transaction in the block.

From Yellow Paper section 4.3 "The Block"

> **stateRoot**: The Keccak 256-bit hash of the root
> node of the state trie, after all transactions are
> executed and finalisations applied; formally H<sub>r</sub>.